# Installing Composer on Windows 7 using windows installer

Tags: php, windows, composer-php, wampserver

I've been trying to install Composer for a while now and still I could not figure out what I am doing wrong. First I installed WAMP Server 2.5(Windows 7 64-bit), then downloaded and run Composer-Setup.exe, installed shell Menus .

I chose this path 
 `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe`

But once I clicked next I bumped into this:

`Please review this settings PHP version 5.5.12`

`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe.`

Which settings should I use instead? When I try to run composer it does start but then shuts down immediately.